# How to compare Localized string with the string from the database?

Tags: ios, swift, arabic

I have a to compare a string with the string from the db.

```
var variableFromDB = "test"
if "test" == variableFromDB{
    print("Success")
}
```

It works fine in the English Language. I don't know how to compare it in the arabic language. Is the need to check in arabic language also. Please tell me know to check it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Have you got an example that doesn't work?  Show us the failing version (as a [mcve]) and its output, as well as the expected output, and you'll be more likely to find someone able to help.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's a bad idea for your code to make decisions based on display strings. That goes double for display strings.

If your primary audience is Arabic-speaking, you could make your development language Arabic and then localize for other languages as needed.

In any case, I would suggest using a set of fixed strings as keys, and then calling `NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:bundle:value:comment:)` or one of it's variants to fetch a display string. Example:

Put this code somewhere central so the keys can be shared:

```
let screen1Prompt = "screen1Prompt"
```

Then when you need a localized string for display:

```
let prompt = NSLocalizedString(screen1Prompt)
```

Where the actual prompt string might be "Please select the date for your payment." in English, Arabic, etc.

Then if you need to match something in your database, look it up using the unlocalized key, not the localized display string.

That way if you later change the display string, your code still works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var language: String

UserDefaults.standard.set("AE", forKey: "Apple") // manually set language 
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
self.language = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Apple")as! String

// self.language = Locale.current.languageCode // your device language

extension String {
func stringlocalized(lang:String) ->String {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
    let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)

    return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
}}
```

// Check You Localization string from your current language

```
 let str  = “ test”.localized(lang:  self.language! )

if str ==variableFromDB 
{ // Your logic here
}
```